# Can't retrieve specific items from a Collection in Excel VBA, even though .count is correct

Tags: excel, vba, collections

I've added items to my collection, named "Questions". I know it adds items to the collection because Questions.count is the right result in various scenarios. However, I'm unable to extract the value of individual .items within the collection.

It gives me the following error: "Invalid procedure call or argument"

So obviously, there must be something basic I don't understand about collections (I only recently learned about them, please be patient with me).

I'm using the methods that I've found online, specifically:

The site https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/ says I should be able to do this:

"You can also use the Item Property to access an item in the collection. It is the default method of the collection so the following lines of code are equivalent:

```
    Debug.Print coll(1)
    Debug.Print coll.Item(1)"
```

Doesn't work for me, no idea why.

```
'[1] SELECT BOX
Dim SelectedBox As Long
    SelectedBox = Box 'NEED TO CONVERT RESULT OF FUNCTION "BOX" TO A VARIABLE WITH TYPE LONG

'[2] TEST CRITERIA FOR QUESTION
Dim Questions As New Collection

Dim SubjectRange As Long
    SubjectRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cmbTopics.Text).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim BoxMatch As Boolean
Dim ChapterMatch As Boolean

'TEST EACH QUESTION IN TOPIC (DETERMINED BY LISTBOX SELECTIONS)
For X = 2 To SubjectRange
BoxMatch = False 'SAYS WHETHER IT PASSED THE TEST
ChapterMatch = False 'SAYS WHETHER IT PASSED THE TEST

    'IS QUESTION IN THE RIGHT BOX?
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cmbTopics.Text).Range("D" & X).Value = SelectedBox Then
    BoxMatch = True
    End If

    'IS QUESTION IN THE RIGHT CHAPTER?
    For Y = 0 To lbChapters.ListCount - 1
    If _
        lbChapters.List(Y) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cmbTopics.Text).Range("B" & X).Value And _
        lbChapters.Selected(Y) = True _
    Then
    ChapterMatch = True
    Next Y

    'IF SO, THEN ADD IT TO THE LIST OF CANDIDATE QUESTIONS ("QUESTIONS")
    If BoxMatch = True And ChapterMatch = True Then
    Questions.Add ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cmbTopics.Text).Range("A" & X).Value
    End If

Next X

'MsgBox ("Matches: " & Questions.Count)

Dim n As Long
    n = RndBetween(1, Questions.Count)
MsgBox (Questions.Item(n))
```

I want to be able to extract the string that should be at the location specified by the code.

Comment: Side-note; You can simplify If BoxMatch = True And ChapterMatch = True Then to If BoxMatch  And ChapterMatch Then

Comment: Very nice, I'm always trying to simplify my code. Great contribution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw you said that Questions.count should be greater than 0 but it would result in the error you are seeing. To be sure you should add:

```
If Questions.count > 0 then
    MsgBox (Questions.Item(n))
Else
    MsgBox ("Questions was empty")
end if
```

Also check that "n" is being returned as an integer.

Comment: Yup, this solved the problem. I was running the function in another place, where the form initializes, before the values are set. So even though in the code here, I've ensured that the collection won't be zero (in the "Box" function, not included here), that's not the case elsewhere that the function runs. Never woulda caught this, thanks.

Comment: you don't need the () after  MsgBox

Comment: JFYI `Collection.Count` returns a `Long`-Value, `Collection.Item(n)` takes a `Long`-Value, so I would stick to `Long` in any case. Also "under the hood" vba stores `Integers` as `Long` datatypes, so there is no practical benefit to using `Integers`. (barring some Edge-Cases)

Comment: Thanks, apologies if I was unclear but I was meaning integer in the common language sense (i.e. a whole number) rather than coding as I wasn't sure what the RndBetween function was returning (I was concerned it could have been decimal).